# Getting 419 Page expired on my return URL while integrating Jazzcash Payment Integration

Tags: php, laravel, payment-gateway

[image]
I am trying to integration Jazzcash in my Laravel Project. Whenever i try to do checkout it redirect to Jazzcash Payment page but before page load it redirect me back to my return URL with 419 Page expired while all of my parameters got success in API log inside Jazzcash Sandbox account but Payment got failed.

Comment: The 419 error tells you the csrf token does not match. add the return URI to the `$except` array in app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php

Comment: Dear token already is there but only issue is that maybe there is something i miss regarding integrate Jazzcash payment gateway

Comment: The token can't be correct since the request from the return URL does not come from Laravel.

Answer (score 3):

Callback url is a `post` request coming from Jazzcash. Since every laravel post request require `csrf` token it will throw 419 error because that request will not contain any token. So to ignore token for that particular url you need to add that url in `VerifyCsrfToken.php` middleware.

In file add that route in `$except` array.

```
protected $except = [
'name-of-your-route'
];
```

Comment: Thanks, Although issue of 419 resolved but still getting no response from Payment Integration

Comment: Did you know how to resolve this issue? I add screenshot of return url response